# Check when a user has clicked a link on a newsletter

Tags: email, mailchimp, newsletter

I want to get the user e-mail when the user clicks a link on a newsletter sent to that user.
Can somebody give any advice on how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use UTM code out of Google Analytics.

**Example**:

```
      https://placeholder.com/?utm_source=emailprovider&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=stackoverflowquestion
```

**More information**:

- https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en
- https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Jets You're supposed to click that you like the answer. This closes out the question.